# Laravel CSRF vulnerability

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have been questioned by my client's security team that our Laravel 5 application is susceptible CSRF vulnerability. We have followed all the standard practice described in Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf where by we have attached the hidden field `_token` in our forms.

The security team claims that CSRF attack can happen when the form html is copy and saved as `name.html` and execute this `.html` file directly from browser.

Here is the sample form HTML

```
<html>
  <!-- CSRF PoC - generated by Burp Suite Professional -->
  <body>
  <script>history.pushState('', '', '/')</script>
    <form action="ourapp.dev/profile/update" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="1heEqemUlHX2vtj2YcgZfq4UGdY07H9rdeRdgtaweE" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
      <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John" />
      <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not 100% sure if the claim is valid as I don't think the attacker can get the csrf token `_token` correctly as the token is unique for each user's session.

Can anyone help to comment on this?

Comment: Why not discuss this topic with the security team? If they really care about the application, they should be able to explain you why this is a security issue. Additionally, be warned that Laravel 5 is no longer supported, so any security issues arising from Laravel itself are not fixed

Comment: I suppose you use Laravel 5.8 as stated in the question, if not versions 5.4 and 5.6 contains some known vulnerabilities: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-16542/Laravel.html

Comment: Ok. We are aware that 5 is no longer supported. We will update to latest version within days. We are more concern on the attack method described whether it does make sense or not?

Comment: Well have you tried to reproduce it? Have you asked for step by step instructions from the people who claimed they've found it? That's the conversation you need to have first.

Comment: Yes. I have tried and reproduced it successfully when we have this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="1heEqemUlHX2vtj2YcgZfq4UGdY07H9rdeRdgtaweE" />` token field in our copied HTML form.

Comment: Well that should answer your question then, I think.

Comment: The most important followup question is: is this reproducible multiple times (such that the token is not invalidated after being used)? Is this reproducible only with a cookie (meaning: the token is useless without the session cookie)?